# SQL Server 2008 Passing multiple variables in a query and combining the rows into one dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the query below that returns one row result for a location. I would want to pass a set number i.e say the 5 sets of filters below i.e for location 1,2,3,4,5 and combine the 1 row results into one dataset i.e 5 rows

I could repeat the query and hardcode it and then use `Union`. This could get large so is there a simple way to do...The list can also be placed in a table

```
@top = 5,4,3,10,20 
@LocationID = 1,2,3,4,5
@Dept = 'AAA',''BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE' 

Declare @top int    
Declare @locationID int 
Declare @Dept varchar(20)

Set @top = 5   
Set @LocationID = 1  
Set @Dept = 'AAA' 

select  
    AVG(Age) as AvgAge , Balance as BalanceLeft 
from  
    (select top(@Top) 
     from Employee 
     where LocationID = @LocationID and Dept = @Dept 
     order by HireDate desc) as Loc_1
```

Returns 1 row

Comment: I would change this to use a table parameter instead of those dreadful delimited lists. It seems really weird to have a single proc try to get a whole bunch of datasets like this.

Comment: Ah yes i can stick the list in a table

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
with vals as (
      select 1 as rn, 5 as thetop, 1 as locationid, 'AAA' as dept union all
      select 2, 4, 2, 'BBB' union all
      . . .
     )
select AVG(Age) as AvgAge, max(Balance) as BalanceLeft
from (select e.*, vals.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vals.rn order by e.HireDate desc) as seqnum
      from vals cross join Employee e
      where e.LocationID = vals.LocationID And e.Dept = vals.Dept 
     ) t
where seqnum <= thetop
group by rn;
```

Put repeating values in rows in a table, rather than in a string.  Also note that the `balanceleft` column needs some aggregation function, so I arbitrarily added `max()`.  I replaced `top` with row number calculations as well.

Comment: I think he need to select inside val from table rather than union ??